# Creating object reflectively & setting fields

Tags: java, generics

I need help in this scenario using Generics:

```
class A{
}

class B{
}

class AB{
    A aInstance;
    B bInstance;
    //getter & setter for the above.
    setA();
    setB();
}
```

Now, in other part/module I want to do the following:

1)I have just the class names i.e "A", "B" & "AB"

2)I want to create an instance of Class A, B and AB (using the classnames) -- this is done using class.forName -- this is fine.

something like this:

```
Object objA= Class.forName("A").newInstance();

Object objB= Class.forName("B").newInstance();
```

Now I want to create instance of class AB and set objA & objB using the setters in AB.

How to do it through reflection?

3)Then I want to create a ArrayList -- List of type AB -- but note that I have only the class name "AB" not the type as such. How to do this ?

Kindly Help.

Comment: Everything till point 2 is fine. But in point 3, no you can't create a `List<AB>`, given the class name `"AB"` as string. That is simply not possible.

Comment: Always use full qualified class name such as `Class.forName("com.x.y.z.A")`.

Comment: @ point 2) how to reflectively create AB instance & set objA & objB ! sample please !Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not? Can't we just save the objects of class AB in the arrayList? If yes then it has to be like List<AB>

Comment: @TeamIncredible Well, you can store objects of `AB` in an `ArrayList`. But that's a raw list. You can't create an `ArrayList<AB>` without knowing the type name at compile time.